How to use PRAGMA with sqlite3's new autocommit attribute in Python?
Python's sqlite3 module recently introduced the autocommit attribute, which the docs recommend setting to False. I'd like to use this recommended setting for a new project using Python 3.12. However, I'd also like to enforce foreign key constraints in my database. I'm aware that this required setting connection.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;") for every connection. This works when using the default option for autocommit, which is LEGACY_TRANSACTION_CONTROL. Using autocommit=False (as recommended), the foreign key constraints are no longer enforced. If I understand correctly, this is because the PRAGMA only works if no transaction is active, but autocommit=False always implicitly opens a transaction, as explained in the docs.
I found that the following seems to work:
con = sqlite3.connect(path, autocommit=True)
con.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;")
con.autocommit = False

Now my question is: Is this intended behavior from sqlite3 or a bug? If it's intended, is the above workaround the best way to solve this and are there any hidden consequences in doing so, that result in different behavior compared to setting autocommit=False immediately in the connect() call? I'm surprised none of this seems to be documented anywhere, I'd assume foreign key checks are quite commonly desired...
Here's a full minimum working example of all of this:
import sqlite3

# con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", autocommit=sqlite3.LEGACY_TRANSACTION_CONTROL)  # PRAGMA works
# con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", autocommit=False)  # PRAGMA doesn't work
con = sqlite3.connect(":memory:", autocommit=True)  # PRAGMA works, but need to set autocommit=False afterwards
con.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;")
con.autocommit = False

# Super basic two-table example...
con.execute("CREATE TABLE foo(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, baz TEXT UNIQUE)")
con.execute("CREATE TABLE bar(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, bazid INTEGER UNIQUE,"
            "FOREIGN KEY (bazid) REFERENCES foo (id))")

# Insert some values so a foreign key exists
with con:
    con.execute("INSERT INTO foo(baz) VALUES(?)", ("spam",))
    con.execute("INSERT INTO foo(baz) VALUES(?)", ("eggs",))

# This should pass
with con:
    con.execute("INSERT INTO bar(bazid) VALUES(?)", ("1",))

# This should fail
with con:
    con.execute("INSERT INTO bar(bazid) VALUES(?)", ("42",))

con.close()

